# search restaurant based on current geolocation

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, database-design

I have database of restaurants with their exact address and now when user search a restaurant from his mobile device I want to show him restaurant in the the order of distance from his current location so that restaurant which is very close comes first in the result. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at [Places Nearby search requests](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests) there is a `google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE` option that will do what you want.

Comment: I want to find the closest of those restaurant whose geo location (latitude and longitude) values I have stored in my own DB. From user I will get his geolocation which I can get using HTML5.

Comment: Ok then. What database do you use? All this is information you should put in your question in first place. You will get a quicker answer if your question is clear and complete.

Comment: I thought type of database is not relevant in this. I had mentioned in the original query "I have database of restaurants with their exact address ......" . I am using mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You can use what is called the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

The below example is for PHP/MySQL but the query is still what you need.

```
$sql = "SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(" . $lat . ") ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(" . $lng . ") ) + sin( radians(" . $lat . ") ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM your_table HAVING distance < 5";
```

Where `$lat` and `$lng` are the coordinates of your point, and lat/lng are your table columns. The above will list the locations within a 5 nm range. Replace `3959` by `6371` to change to kilometers.

This link could be useful: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

You can add an `order by` clause to order the results by `distance`.